# Unit testing tools for generating boundary conditions

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing

i just wondered if there are any alternative tools out there like [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) for automatic generating boundary conditions for unit tests (should work with NUnit)?
Personally i would prefer using Pex, but the license conditions from Microsoft Research Labs do not allow commercial use under Visuals Studio 2008 Professional (what does not make any sense to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after Pex-like functionality, there's probably nothing like it out there. And yes, the Pex licensing really is confusing, I mean, disallowing commercial use of something that doesn't even get released to the customer - strikes me as strange, to say the least.

Comment: Well, commercial use seems to be allowed but the DevLabs Pre-Release for commercial evaluation only works with the Team edition of VS2008

Answer (score 0):

The best place to voice your licensing concerns is in the Pex forums themselves, specifically in this post:
[Pex for VS Pro](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/52763686-3eb6-47cf-950d-21b2baa07423).

Peli, a Pex developer.